# delay in ouput of combined c++ program

Tags: c++

i have two programs in c++. one is to communicate with arduino(**pgm1**),while the  other is an openCV program reading a webcam(**pgm2**). independently, they work at moral speed.

if we open them simultaneously in different terminals they work perfect.i wanted to join them as a single program, i tried a program **(pgm3)**. i can get images perfectly in real time.. but the data from arduino delays about 7-10 seconds. unfortunately i know only c/c++/embedded c. so kindly refer me a solution in any one of these languages

pgm1

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char ch;
ifstream f;
f.open("/dev/ttyACM0");
while (f.get(ch)) 
{
cout<<ch;   
if(ch=='#')
cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

pgm2

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
/** Function Headers */
String window_name = "webcam c170 preview";
/** @function main */
int main( void )
{
VideoCapture capture;
Mat frame;

capture.open( 1 );
if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }

while ( capture.read(frame) )
{
    if( frame.empty() )
    {
        printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
        break;
    }

    //-- 3. show frames
    imshow( window_name, frame );
    int c = waitKey(30);
    if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
}
return 0;
}
}
```

pgm3

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
void spi_read(void);
/** Global variables */
char ch;
ifstream f;
String window_name = "webcam c170 preview";
/** @function main */
int main( void )
{
VideoCapture capture;
Mat frame;
f.open("/dev/ttyACM0");
capture.open( 1 );
if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }

while ( capture.read(frame) )
{
    if( frame.empty() )
    {
        printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
        break;
    }   
    //-- 3. show frames
    imshow( window_name, frame );
    int c = waitKey(30);
    if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
spi_read();
}
return 0;
}
void spi_read()
{
String str_spi;
do
{
    f.get(ch);
    str_spi=str_spi+ch;
}while(ch!='#');
cout<<str_spi<<endl;

}
```

Comment: "moral speed"?  What do you mean?

Comment: Seeing the OpenCV includes at the top of such cluttered, unreadable and messy code is **just scary.**

Comment: i meant "normal speed"  by telling "moral speed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not just merge to code into one function - of course it will cause your second program to "delay" - because its starts to execute after ur previos code is done.
You should create separate thread to simulate ur pgm1/pgm2 programs and then maybe process data received by them in ur main thread - depending on your needs.
Most straighforward solution using boost/thread:

```
void do_what_pgm1_does() {..}  
void do_what_pgm2_does() {..}
int main()
{
  boost::thread t1(do_what_pgm1_does);  
  boost::thread t2(do_what_pgm2_does);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```

this will give you similar execution as you had with 2 processes.

Comment: well thanks for your support,the program says boost,thread are all unidentified is there any header files in which "boost" is defined??

Comment: do u have access to c++11? If so then you can replace boost:: with std::. Boost is open source library available at http://www.boost.org/

Comment: i dont..will [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm) be helpful??

Comment: yea, you can take a look at this sample and try to replicate it.